# What are the MySQL queries for the following tasks? Are my solutions and line of thinking correct so far? Thank you very much

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is my very first question on Quora. Thanks for any recommendations , solutions and remarks.  I was not provided with many specifics and data, this is a assignments where one must use his or her imagination to fill in particular data and variables. What counts is the correct logic, approach and covering possibilities. Your help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

[Country and Continent table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCGgo.jpg)

[Required Visual Result for Question 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZeYf.jpg)

**Questions:**

1. Write a query that would select all countries with GDP of more than 1 000 000 000 USD
2. Write a query that would return all countries in Europe (specifically) with GDP of more than 1 000 000 000 USD
3. Write a query that lists all continents with GDP per continent (as the sum of the GDP of all countries). Each country belong to one continent only.
   For what result should look like - please resort to "Required Visual Result for Question 3" image.

**My Solutions:**

1. `select * from countries where GDP > 1000000000`
2. `select * from countries where continent_id = 2 and GDP>1000000000;`
3. `select sum(GDP) from countries where continent_id = 4;`

However, here in 3) I can only have the GDP sum displayed, and do not know how to have the continent's name on the left side as well. Please, if possible, assist with having the continent's name displayed and then right next to it and on the right handside - the relevant GDP sum.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for a bit of help with your homework. Beginners are welcome, but we expect a good faith attempt at an answer from you first. 
___SO is not a free coding service___ although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.
[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)
. Look up the JOIN syntax in any SQL Query tutorial.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`. (q 3)

Comment: Also, you should write q2 as a `JOIN`, where you give `'Europe'` as input, not 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!

Your image shows the tables as country and continent but your queries refer to countries? So which is it please?

On the basis your image is correct but the queries are wrong then number 3 would be as below:

With no 3 your currently only going to get the some for the continent with the ID of 4.

```
select sum(GDP) from country where continent_id = 4;
```

So what you want to do is remove the WHERE and the GROUP BY continent_id to give you 1 result per continent.

```
select sum(GDP) from country where 1 GROUP BY continent_id
```

No to get the continent name included in your results you can use the JOIN syntax.

In this instance you want all your records from country and just the records from continent that match your join condition which will be the continent_id from country and the id from the continent table.

```
SELECT 
`continent`.`name`, sum(`GDP`) 
FROM `country` 
LEFT JOIN `continent` 
ON `country`.`continent_id` = `continent`.`id` 
GROUP BY `continent_id` 
ORDER BY `continent`.`name` ASC;
```

That should give you the results 1 per continent as required.

I've specified the table `names` as its clearer how to target specific columns from each table.

Comment: Thank you, @UrbanwarfareStudios, you are correct about the approach! Now the only trouble seems to be that I am getting the double sum of what the actual sum is supposed to be. Is there a way t fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Unless I am missing something obvious (and without seeing your actual data) it sounds like you might have duplicate entries in your country table?

If you run this what do you get?

SELECT 
`continent_id`, sum(`GDP`) 
FROM `country` 
GROUP BY `continent_id`

Comment: I think that was it, thanks a lot. It worked. :)

Comment: you are very welcome